# Can I use Python instead of Javascript in front-end development?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am asking this because I don't want to use Javascript; instead I want to use Python as an alternative.
If this is not possible, please give an alternative apart from jQuery.

Comment: jQuery and JavaScript are not synonymous. While I think there are growing solutions for embedding Python in HTML, you really should think more about your reasons for avoiding another language; if it's just that you don't want to learn another language, that isn't a very good reason

Comment: Yes, you can do this. There are three webhosts ***that I know of*** that provide server-side Python alongside HTML etc - A2, Namecheap and webhostpython.com

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of projects to bring python to browsers, for example http://brython.info, all are not production-ready.

You can use transpiled languages (your code transformed into JS to be run by a browser). Typescript is one of the options.

In the end web development == Javascript, so you should grit your teeth and just use the right tool for the job. There are many frameworks available to make JS development less painful: vue.js, angular, react, many others...

Comment: +1 for mentioning they are not prod-ready - i just wanted to add that webassembly is a real possibility nowadays. you can program most if not all functionality of your site in (i.e.) rust, compile that to webassembly and it will run on all modern browsers.

Comment: @MCO I wasn’t aware that WASM has advanced so far:)

Comment: wasm itself is pretty solid, what's dragging is the support for (or from?) various languages. so far, not that many are truly production-ready (see https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs) - and that's all just basic compiler support, it can still be a pain to port external dependancies, mainly bigger frameworks and anything that expects IO outside the browser's sandbox, so we probably won't see big apps being ported anytime soon. But you can already write stuff specifically for your website :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.You can first you need to download XMAPP AND Python3 then open XMAPP -> apache config notepad will be open then find AddHandler.  AddHandler-> AddHandler cgi-script.cgi.pl.asp.py -> save it.Then the .py extension created.

Comment: given that they asked for jQuery alternatives, i'm pretty sure they are looking at client-side options, not server-side.